# Use of fat arrow functions in JSFiddle with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, jsfiddle

I've had some snippets on JSFiddle for some blog posts using TypeScript, but some of them have stopped working.

Specifically it's when I use the fat arrow notation for function definitions.
It have been working before, so maybe I need to set some options on JSFiddle?

Here is a simple example: https://jsfiddle.net/CaveOfCode/3wdme693/1/
With the following snippet:

```
const fatArrow = () => console.log("fatArrow");
fatArrow();
const functionKeyword = function() { console.log("functionKeyword"); };
functionKeyword();
```

The `fatArrow` throws the error.

```
VM111:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Comment: You do not have braces wrapped around the fatArrow function.  Not sure if that's a newer requirement, or if it's something in what JSFiddle uses to transpile (I've always just had them in place just incase).  But if you change your fatArrow method to `const fatArrow = () => { console.log("fatArrow"); }` it works.

Comment: When omitting the braces, you save some keystrokes. It is short for `const fatArrow = () => { return console.log("fatArrow"); }`. Anyways, until it's fixed I update my code to this for now. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Their TypeScript integration is broken as you can see on the console

[image]

Worth contacting them through different channels : http://doc.jsfiddle.net/meta/channels.html

Your code is correct (as you probably know).